# How to set speed dial from ios app?

Tags: ios

In my app I'm have a option for speed dial. If I click on it, It have to make a speed dial on home screen or in dial pad(i.e if I click on a crated shortcut on home screen or in keypad, it has to make a call to a particular number). Is it possible in ios? if so please suggest me how to achieve this?.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't know of any public API that allows this.

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible in iOS, you cannot create shortcuts on the home screen from a third party app. Shortcut icons can only be made from Safari, and only one that points to a safari URL that is accessible (meaning no tel: links)

Comment: is it possible create short cut from safari?

Comment: Not programmatically, but the user has to manually create it. You could setup a web service that 301 redirects to a tel link that the user sets, but only AFTER they have had a chance to bookmark it. This woul open the telephone app but not press send. But this is not going to be possible from a 3rd party iOS app

Comment: okay thanks @coneybeare. So can I do it by using below?
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"some URL"]]; 
From this they can add it to their home screen by using add to home screen at the botom of safari browser. is it correct?

Comment: sure, if you had a website that you directed them to that on first launch would show a page asking them to add it to the home screen, such http://yoursite.com/tel/1234567890. The first time they launched it, it would not 301 redirect to allow the user to set the bookmark on the home screen. After you make it redirect on your server, anytime the user goes back to that site using the bookmark, they will then get redirected to tel:1234567890.

Comment: Thanks... I have done this using safari... But is there a possibility to add speed dial without clicking add speed dial(at the bottom) in safari? or directly asking for add speed dial?

Comment: No, there is not a way

Comment: Okay thanks... Also need one more clarification is it possible to get call history from our app in ios 7? I read it is possible in ios 4, from the link http://iosstuff.wordpress.com/2011/08/19/accessing-iphone-call-history/. Please suggest

Comment: There is a way to find out... simply try the trick they list in the blog posting.

Comment: I tried it, but I'm getting the response as database file not exist.

Comment: Then there is your answer.

Comment: so r u coming to say its not possible in ios 7?